# Travis CI In Sub Directory

Tags: travis-ci

I have a gem with a subdirectory (`test`) containing a Rails 3.1.1 application used to test the project. I'm trying to setup Travis-CI for continuous integration, however I cannot figure out how to setup my `.travis.yml` configuration. I have:

```
gemfile: test/Gemfile
rvm:
  - 1.8.7
  - 1.9.2
  - 1.9.3
  - jruby
  - ree
script: sh -e 'cd test' && bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate test
```

Which causes:

```
sh: Can't open cd test
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it was an issue with some of the documentation. The script call should have been:

```
script: sh -c 'cd test && bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate test'
```